# Qt style sheets bugs?

Tags: qt, user-interface, styles, stylesheet

I have a many bugs at simple QSS(Qt style sheets). Is it bugs of Qt?

Example:

[image]

Style sheets:

```
#check1 {
  color: red                  //didn't work here
}

#check2 {
  color: red;                 //but work here
  background-color: black
}

#label1 {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline  //work fine here
} 

#label2:hover {
  color: blue; 
  text-decoration: underline  //but didn't work here
}
```

Sources:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setStyleSheet(" #check1 {color: red} \
                        #check2 {color: red; background-color: black}  \
                        #label1 {color: blue; text-decoration: underline}  \
                        #label2:hover {color: blue; text-decoration: underline}");
    QWidget w; w.setFixedSize(120,130);

    QCheckBox check1("checkbox1",&w);
    check1.setObjectName("check1");
    check1.move(10,0);

    QCheckBox check2("checkbox1",&w);
    check2.setObjectName("check2");
    check2.move(10,30);

    QLabel label1("label1", &w);
    label1.setObjectName("label1");
    label1.move(10,60);

    QLabel label2("label2", &w);
    label2.setObjectName("label2");
    label2.move(10,90);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

qt 4.7.3-3; arch linux; gnome 3 fallback mode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the first checkbox, the problem is somewhere in the Gtk+ style:
[image]

`QLabel`, `QPushButton` or `QCheckBox` don't support font changes (including `text-decoration`) in the `:hover` pseudo-state css selector. The simplest widget that does seems to be `QToolButton` (which could be used to replace the QLabels if you really need that). 

Palette changes (foreground and background colors and styles) for that state are supported by all the widgets.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say what the issue with your checkbox is, but the following tidbit can be found in is according to Qt's style sheet reference (I can't find it online, but it's in Qt Assistant)

> QLabel supports the box model. Does not support the :hover pseudo-state.

In other words, QLabel:hover is not supported.

Comment: You're right!  That's odd, because according to their documentation it shouldn't.  I do know from experience, however, that changing the underline does not work as I've tried to do exactly what you're doing here in the past.

Comment: Qt 4.7 DOES support hover http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet-syntax.html#pseudo-states

Comment: I didn't say Qt didn't support the hover pseudo-state, I said that it doesn't support it for QLabels

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
// some comment
```

use

```
/* some comment */
```

. I guess they chose the latter form as it is immune to newline-breakage.

Apart from that, if it is still not okay, then it seems you've run into bugs: https://bugreports.qt-project.org//browse/QTBUG-4307 .

As a workaround for setting only the text color, try out

```
#check1:hover { color:red; background-color:transparent; }
```

which worked for me.

Comment: Comments have been added only in the question, they are not exists in the source code

Comment: @TheHorse: that should have been mentioned in the question; as is, my answer still applies

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
color: red
```

be

```
color: red;
```

?

Missing semicolons a few places in your posted code.

Comment: A semicolon is not required after the last item.

Comment: ...or maybe it is required. Qt is doing the parsing not some browser.  So it is up to Nokia to implement it any way they have time for. I think in general it is a bad habit to assume that every obscure convenience feature of someone else's standard is implemented.  If you look at some other Qt classes, you'll always find something that isn't implemented or implemented in a diff way.  Even browsers don't keep up with all the standards.

Comment: Nothing changed with semicolons

Comment: @user440297: I wasn't just +suggesting+ that maybe a semicolon wasn't required. See http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html.

Comment: Qt Doc examples all omit the last semicolon : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html