# Qt Style Sheet Bugs (7 years later)

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

Hi I am new to Qt and am following up on this question about styling bugs: [Qt style sheets bugs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166403/qt-style-sheets-bugs)

I am trying to style a button (using QTDesigner) such that on hover, the text has the underline decoration.

This code works:

```
#printBtn:hover {
background-color: transparent;  
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This code does not work:

```
#printBtn:hover {   
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Am I missing something about why the text-decoration would be obfuscated by the background-color? The conclusion in the linked stack above, as far as I can tell, is that the QPushButton doesn't support font changes. Is that still correct? It seems like it does support it, but on the condition you do not have a background-color.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt style sheets bugs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166403/qt-style-sheets-bugs)

Comment: @MrEricSir. Did you read the first line of the question?

Comment: @MrEricSir : Nope not a duplicate -- see the first sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a Qt bug, I was able to obtain the same result with Qt 5.10.1.

QPushButton does support font changes. That was not the case before, but it has been "fixed" (see [this commit](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/81426/4/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp)).

I guess the issue is at line 3484 of file qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp:

```
if (rule.hasPosition() && rule.position()->textAlignment != 0) {
```

because the else part of this if clause (line 3556) will call:

```
ParentStyle::drawControl(ce, &butOpt, p, w);
```

In fact, you can force it to work also by setting the text-align:

```
#printBtn:hover {   
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I'm afraid there's not much we can do except filing a bug report at http://bugreports.qt.io.

Comment: Okay thanks for checking and the quick fix! I signed up and reported the bug as best I could.

Comment: Thanks, I commented there as well. Hopefully we will get some support from Qt developers.